# How to deep link to a Facebook App (NOT Page Tab)

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I need to link to a specific page in my Facebook app. **The app is not in a page tab, and cannot be in one due to the project constrictions.**

This is the url format:
https://apps.facebook.com/myappname

I would need to pass a parameter at the end (like /next.html or ?page=next) so that I can link to the specific page directly from outside the app (from an email).

How would I set this up? My project uses PHP and jQuery. I would love to be able to do this strictly in Javascript if possible.

I have found tons of info on how to deep link a page tab or a mobile app, but not to a regular application. I have found messages stating it's possible, but nothing about how to actually do it anywhere online or on Facebook.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

Okay, I got it working in PHP. For anyone else with this issue, this is what I did.

Add a "?" at the very end of the 'Site URL' in your FB app, then create a redirect file similar to this as your app landing page (just use absolute paths instead of relative ones like I did below):

```
<?php
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$params = explode("/", $query);

if (in_array("gallery", $params)) {
    header("Location: /gallery.html");
    exit;
}
else {
    header("Location: /index.html");
    exit;
}
?>
```

This answer is what helped me figure this out:
[$_GET on facebook iframe app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414853/get-on-facebook-iframe-app/7734877#7734877)

Comment: Can you show me a sample url on how you access the deep link in the facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the ? all you are doing is issuing a $_GET request, so all of the info you require will exist in the $_GET array.

Rather than query the $_SERVER array, query the $_GET array.

So if you had:

http://myurl.com?info=foobar

You can simply access that info using:

```
$info = $_GET['info'];
```

It is good practice to check for the existence first though:

```
if (isset($_GET['info']))
{
$info =$_GET['info'];
}
else
{
$info="default";
}
```

Incidently if you use the & character you can have multiple parameters:

```
http://myurl.com?info=foo&moreinfo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something here, but why don't you just link to `http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp/something.php` - this should automatically load your canvas URL, with `something.php` appended to the path

Obviously this won't work if your canvas URL points to a specific file and not a directory, but plenty of apps do this with success

Answer (score 0):

You get a special parameter called `app_data` that you can use however you want.  I've used it in the past to encode a full querystring of my internal app.  for example, `&app_data=My/Custom/Page`

More found in this SO question: [Retrieve Parameter From Page Tab URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919541/retrieve-parameter-from-page-tab-url/13920132#13920132)

Comment: This only works in a Page Tab - not in a regular app. This is the answer I was able to find online but again, it doesn't work unless the app lives in a page tab, and I can't use a page tab for this project. Is there another way?

Comment: With a canvas app, you should be able to just use normal GET parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry, how would I do this? I tried passing a parameter to the signed request but I'm not able to retrieve the parameter, maybe I'm approaching this wrong? Here's a fiddle where I tried passing page=gallery: http://jsfiddle.net/C3xsm/8/